# downloading Blob file in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, http-headers, blob

i am using this query to get image saved in medium blob in mysql which calls download function in brands controller

```
SELECT *,CONCAT(\"<img src='../../brands/download/?file_id=\",id,
                        \"&name=\",logo_name,\"'/>\") AS file
                         FROM c_brands WHERE merchant_id=" .$merchant_session;
```

DOWN LOAD FUNCTION

```
function download()
    {
        //$this->view = 'Media';
        Configure::write('debug', 1);
        $id = $_GET["file_id"];
        $file = $this->Brand->findById($id);        

        header('Content-type: ' . $file['Brand']['logo_type']);
        header('Content-length: ' . $file['Brand']['logo_size']);
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$file['Brand']['logo_name']);
        echo $file['Brand']['logo'];
        exit();
    }
```

But somehow it is just displaying the placeholder for image.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more? I mean, what's the relation between the first query (the one with Concat) and the download() action, plus how are you using this query? Also, I notice that you are putting `<img src='../../brands/download/?file_id=\"`, and that relative path is wrong. It must be `src="/brands/download"`.

Still, your question is not clear.

Comment: the query concate statement calls download function in brands controller. and i am displaying the image stored in database to datagrid from this query. and i tried to change from ../../brands/download to /brands/download but it has no effect.

Comment: I still think that the approach you are taking is very weird. Why call a controller action from a SQL query, or why build html within it? Here's an [article on outputting files from database blobs](http://edwardawebb.com/web-development/cakephp/serving-files-cakephp). It's the least I can do.